# Tree-line of Views

Tags: android, android-layout

I am kind of new to programming and I am currently working on a project where one of the activities opens a dialog that has a tree line made of a View. I would like some kind of a line to connect each Parent to its child.

Of course, I do not want you to code the whole thing, but would be grateful if someone pointed me in the right direction :)

The end result I am looking for: http://draw.to/D3twQfS

Thanks in advance.

P.S.: Each parent ImageView will have maximum 2-4 children ImageViews

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the people in a `RelativeLayout` and add a vertical line (`View`) underneath/above the picture (`ImageView`) and center it horizontally.
Then all you need to do is add a horizontal line (`View`) to connect the lines.
Put all the people from the same generation in a horizontal `LinearLayout` and put all those `LinearLayouts` in a vertical `LinearLayout`.

This is how I would tackle this!

EDIT: For all generations, add the maximum amount of people (as you said: 4) in the horizontal `LinearLayout` and give the `RelativeLayout` (a person) a `weight` of 1. Than on runtime you can remove the unused people (if the generation contains less than 4 people) by using `setVisibility(View.GONE)`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it makes sense. I didn't think about visibility! I know what to do now lol. Thank you! .. StackO isn't letting me accept your answer for now. Got to wait 2 mins